# Function bounded a. e.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I have a question: if $f$ is uniformly bounded in $L^2(0,T,X)$ , then $f$ is uniformly bounded a.e. in $X \times (0,T).$ If yes, how to prove it? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by unfiformly bounded in $X\times (0,T)$? What is $X$?

Comment: "$f$ is uniformly bounded in $L^2(0,T,X)$" : uniformly with respect to what ? What is $X$ by the way ?

Comment: Oh, X is an open bounded of $\mathbb{R}^n$. In summary, Is true that if
$||y_n||_{L^2(0,T,X)}\leq M,$ then $|y_n(x,t)|\leq\,M$ a.e. in $X\times(0,T)?$

Comment: What happens in your attempts to find a counterexample?

Answer (score 0):

It's not true even for classical $L^2$ space (then the counter-example can be generalized). Take $f_n:=\sqrt n \chi_{(0,1/n)}$: this sequence is bounded in $L^2$, but not in $L^\infty$.